# show all the restaurants that each student can go to and have at least one dessert that they like

Tags: sql, rows

This is my first time posting in a forum as I've never gone this route before in trying to determine what exactly I'm missing.

This is what I'm trying to do:
Write an SQL query to show all the restaurants that each student can go to and have at least one dessert that they like. i.e. If a restaurant has a dessert that the person likes, then the person can go to that restaurant.
This is what I have for the database so far (tables, fields, composite tables, etc):

```
create table Student
(
    StudentID int primary key not null
    , LastName nvarchar (20) not null
    , FirstName nvarchar (20) not null
)

create table Dessert 
(
    DessertID int primary key not null
    , DessertName nvarchar (25) not null
)

create table Restaurant 
(
    RestaurantID int primary key not null
    , RestaurantName nvarchar (20) not null
    , RestaurantStreet nvarchar (20) not null
    , RestaurantCity nvarchar (20) not null
    , RestaurantState nvarchar (2) not null
    , RestaurantZipCode nvarchar (5) not null
)

create table StudentDessert 
(
    StudentID int
    , DessertID int
    , primary key (StudentID, DessertID)
    , foreign key (StudentID) references Student(StudentID)
    , foreign key (DessertID) references Dessert(DessertID)
) 

create table RestaurantDessert 
(
    RestaurantID int
    , DessertID int
    , primary key (RestaurantID,DessertID)
    , foreign key (restaurantID)references Restaurant(RestaurantID)
    , foreign key (DessertID) references Dessert(DessertID)
)
```

This is probably the closest I've gotten but it still produces way too much data:

```
select restaurantname, studentID, dessertid
from restaurant, studentdessert
where dessertid != 0
```

Can you please help refine this query?

Comment: It would be useful to provide the columns in the tables `restaurant` and `studentdessert` so people can help you with your query.

Comment: hey, welcome, what you wanna do is a join take a look https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp 
And also to have more chance to get answer in the future take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is what I have for the database so far (tables, fields, composite tables, etc):
StudentID int primary key not null,
LastName nvarchar (20) not null, 
FirstName nvarchar (20) not null,
create table Dessert
DessertID int primary key not null, 
DessertName nvarchar (25) not null,
create table Restaurant
RestaurantID int primary key not null, 
RestaurantName nvarchar (20) not null,
RestaurantStreet nvarchar (20) not null, 
RestaurantCity nvarchar (20) not null, 
RestaurantState nvarchar (2) not null,
RestaurantZipCode nvarchar (5) not null,

Comment: create table StudentDessert
StudentID int,
DessertID int,
primary key (StudentID, DessertID),
foreign key (StudentID) references Student(StudentID),
foreign key (DessertID) references Dessert(DessertID),
create table RestaurantDessert
RestaurantID int,
DessertID int, 
primary key (RestaurantID,DessertID),
foreign key (restaurantID)references Restaurant(RestaurantID),
foreign key (DessertID) references Dessert(DessertID),

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and show us what you want your results to look like?

Comment: Good coding practices for writing `JOINs`  is to explicitly define them, rather than using implicit syntax (`from restaurant, studentdessert`).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want your results to look, but here's a simple query that will get you going in the right direction:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName AS 'StudentName'
        ,r.RestaurantName
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN StudentDessert sd ON sd.StudentID = s.StudentID
INNER JOIN dessert de ON de.DessertID = sd.DessertID
INNER JOIN RestaurantDessert rd ON rd.DessertID = sd.DessertID
INNER JOIN Restaurant r ON r.RestaurantID = rd.RestaurantID
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this digital.aaron.  This is what I was looking for. 
Breaking it down, if I'm not mistaken, the SELECT statement is pulling the first and last names from the student table and combining them into the Student Name field.  It is also pulling the restaurant name from the restaurant table and inserting that into the second field. 

in order to produce the required data without the redundancy, the inner joins are then joining the primary keys (ID fields) of each table to reference the value of data inserted into the requested tables.

Comment: I was not using the correct join to produce the results I needed for my database.  I had been trying to use an implicit join instead.